# How to convert from unicode list to normal list in python/django

Tags: python, django

How can i convert this list:

```
list = [u"[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']"]into this list:
```

to:

```
[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']
```

I tried this :

```
n = ast.literal_eval(list)
```

but i got this error:

> ValueError: malformed string

what else can i do to change this list without "u"?

Comment: First question would be: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i want to compare it to another list which does not contain "u" outside the list

Comment: Although you've got some good answers here, you should really investigate why you are getting data in this odd format, and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `malformed string` because `literal_eval` is expecting a string, but you are passing it a list. Look at the outermost delimiters. For a string they should be matched quotes but you have square brackets.

```
>>> mylist = [u"[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']"]
>>> ast.literal_eval(mylist.pop())
[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']   # in Python 2
['book1', 'book2', 'book3']      # in Python 3
```

Answer (score 3):

`ast.literal_eval` takes as parameter a node or a string.
A list is neither. The first value in your example list is a string,
you can pass that:

```
alist = [u"[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']"]
ast.literal_eval(alist[0])
# produces: ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
```

Comment: I have a similar list list= [u'book1', u'book2'] but when i do ast.literal_eval(list[0]), i get malformed string though list[0] is a string.

Comment: @avleen01 if you have `list= [u'book1', u'book2']` then you don't need to use `ast.literal_eval`, and in fact it makes no sense. It's a Python list of string values. In any case, I don't really understand what you're asking with this follow-up question. Please explain better what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list's data is safe you can use `eval()`:

```
>>> a = [u"[u'book1', u'book2', u'book3']"]
>>> eval(a[0])
['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
```

Otherwise, the safest option is to use `literal_eval` from `ast` module:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(a[0])
['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
```